# Ethics of Returning an Item Broken by Ignorance

Tags: electrical

Here is the scenario:

I purchased and installed a timer switch that didn't work. At first I assumed it was a bad switch and exchanged it for a new one.

The second one briefly worked and promptly died.

At this point I realized that I was mistaking the red wire for a white/gray wire (I'm color blind).

In this case it was an innocent mistake and I'm quite certain the retailer will exchange it. The question is: should I exchange it again after realizing it was my fault? What are the ethics of returning a product broken through ignorance? What if it's a brand new drill bit that snapped on the first use or a battery that was charged improperly?

As DIYers we take risk in not hiring a professional. Are we willing to accept the consequences when we make a mistake?

Comment: Not really on-topic for DIY.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about ethics and legality vs. diy home inprovement.

Comment: I worked with a couple of guys who were color-blind - whenever they had to take wires off something they asked for help - 30 seconds is all it takes to check but can save a lot of damage.. And they were always prepared to help me when asked.

Comment: Not sure if there is an SE site this would be better suited for, but what I would do is take it back and tell them that you think it broke because the wires are identified only by color not with a tag. Don't ask for a return, just make it a complaint, and see if they offer a return/exchange. Also ask if they have one that accomodates your visual impairment (lots of switches I've bought have little tags on the pigtail wires identifying their purpose in addition to just the color).

Comment: @PhilippNagel Citroen did that for years on car wires : all black with little tags with numbers... they soon wore off, a real pia...

Comment: @SolarMike Interesting. At least typical house wiring does not get worked on nearly as much as a french car's electrical system, so the tags should stay put a bit longer.

Comment: If you are that badly color blind, you shouldn't be working on electric wires at all. You could cause injury, fire, and death.

Comment: @Phil Freedenberg Does that mean I shouldn't drive either? We all take risks in life. I'm comfortable taking this risk. FYI ~10% of men are color blind. It's very common.

Comment: @jwh20 Close the question if you think that is appropriate. I carefully searched stack exchange for an appropriate forum before asking here.

Comment: @Solar Mike: Covid makes it difficult to find help right now.

Comment: If you have to ask, you know it's unethical....

Answer (score 3):

That's a question to be answered only by your moral compass but whatever you do, let them know it's bad so they don't stick it back on the shelf so someone else buys it and has problems.... think of the other DIY'ers.

Answer (score 2):

Big box retailers will theoretically let you return items for any reason, any number of times. They want the buyer to be happy. Especially DIY stores - they know that a lot of people aren't qualified to use many of the products they sell (this includes color-blind people working on electrics).

What actually happens, however, is that the return is recorded by a company called The Retail Equation. They score purchasers on various statistics (the details are a company secret); if your behavior falls outside their determined norm, then you'll find that future returns become hard to get - you start having to provide more evidence such as receipts. At the extreme - if you return a large proportion of everything you buy, for example, they will prevent you returning anything at all. If a membership is involved (warehouses, Amazon Prime), you may find that the membership is cancelled.

Comment: It gets into an interesting problem: Returns without receipts. I try to always have my receipt, but once I returned at Home Depot without a receipt (just couldn't find it as the product died a while after I bought it but well under warranty & return policies). They were able to find it by my credit card number. Which was amazing and perfect for me. But it is a double-edged sword. Pay cash all the time (and don't use a "loyalty card" - this is one reason many stores have such things) and they **can't** track you - but then you more often (depending on store, value of return, etc.) **have to**

Comment: provide a receipt. Use the same card all the time and they can verify easily without a receipt (and give you full credit - otherwise without a receipt it is typically "lowest sale price for the item in last 'n' days") but they have the ability (and arguably responsibility to their shareholders) to track excessive returns to deter fraudulent activity. In many places, especially with self checkout, somebody could buy 3 'x' but walk out the store with 4 'x' (who can tell with a full cart) and then return 3 'x' and still have one for free (which would have been harder for them to simply walk out

Comment: by itself. Or many other possible fraudulent schemes. Trust me, they've (any retailer, large & small, pretty much anywhere in the world) have seen it all. A good store **wants** to make legitimate customers happy (even if the customers make mistakes that could/should have been avoided). And they will go out of their way to accommodate such issues (I know Home Depot has for me) but they still have to combat fraud.

Comment: @manassehkatz when you use a credit card, they know exactly what you paid for it and when.  Unless you bought multiple units at different prices.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That's one of my points. Pay by credit card and return is effectively "return with receipt" - for good (you get the full price you paid back) or bad (they know you keep returning things *all the time*). Actually worse than "return with receipt" because they can link everything together.